# Problems when installing cocos2dx in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cocos2d-x

I am using visual studio express c++ 2010. I was following [this tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7), and all went well until i tried building the HelloCpp project using ctrl-F5. In the end, the IDE tells me that libBox2d cannot be started. How can I fix this?

Comment: Right click on project you want to run and then click `Set as Startup` and run it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you have the libBox2d target selected. Static libraries can't be run/started.

You will want to change the active target to the actual app target. I'm not sure how to do this in VS but usually there will be a dropdown. Look for any control currently labelled libBox2d or Box2d and click that.